# Codeigniter Where clause not working

Tags: sql, codeigniter-3, where-clause

Codeigniter Where clause does not work while use Variable. If I use number directly for $price_min this should be work.

while I use

`$s=$this->db->where(' prize < ' , $price_max);`

this will be return

```
prize < [value] => '100' .
```

while I use `$s=$this->db->where(' prize < ' , 100);`

this will return

```
prize < [value] => 100 .
```

I think While I use variable this return to be string. How to change it to be integer?
Please follow my codes

```
function filter()
{      
        $state = $this->input->post("state");
        $type = $this->input->post('type');
        $bed = $this->input->post('bed');
        $bath = $this->input->post('bath');
    echo    $price_min=$this->input->post("price-min");  //output: 5

    echo    $price_max=$this->input->post("price-max");  //output: 100
        $this->db->where(' prize > ' , $price_min);
    $s=$this->db->where(' prize < ' , $price_max); 
    print_r($s); 
        $filterquery = $this->db->get('details');
        $records= $filterquery->result();
        return array(
            'records' => $records,
            'count' => count($records),
        );

}
```

Comment: `echo    $price_min=$this->input->post("price-min");` prints the value?

Comment: echo $price_min print the value. If  I use following code that's work                           $this->db->where(' prize > ' , 5);
    $this->db->where(' prize < ' , 100);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will work for you:

```
function filter()
{      
    $state = $this->input->post("state");
    $type = $this->input->post('type');
    $bed = $this->input->post('bed');
    $bath = $this->input->post('bath');

    $price_min = $this->input->post("price-min");
    $price_max = $this->input->post("price-max");

    /*you can set 0 or whatever if post is empty i set null */
    $price_min = ! empty($price_min) ? intval($price_min) : NULL;
    $price_max = ! empty($price_max) ? intval($price_max) : NULL;

    /* you can also check with if statement
       if ($price_min != '' && $price_max != '') {
          $price_max  = intval($price_max);
          $price_min = intval($price_min);
          your where statement.....
       }
    */
    $this->db->where('prize >' , $price_min);
    $this->db->where('prize <' , $price_max);

    $filterquery = $this->db->get('details');
    $records = $filterquery->result();
    return array(
        'records' => $records,
        'count' => count($records),
    );
}
```

Comment: I use noUi slider, So $price_min and $price_max not an empty. Please view my edited question.

Comment: is my answer helps you or you still getting the same ?

Comment: while use $price_min = ! empty($price_min) ? intval($price_min) : NULL;
    $price_max = ! empty($price_max) ? intval($price_max) : NULL;      this get error    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND `prize` < 100' at line 4

SELECT * FROM `details` WHERE `prize` > AND `prize` < 100

Filename: F:/xampp2/htdocs/real-estate/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: I change your code to $price_min = intval($price_min) ;
   $price_max =intval($price_max) ;     it's work Thank you so much

Comment: just to check data is coming and convert it to an int if you don't want to use it use the if statement written in the comment  if you don't want to use if statement also  just use intval to convert string to an int

Comment: if my answer helps you pls check my answer as green